# Change JWT-token composition in OpenAm

Tags: openam

When I enabled stateless sessions in OpenAm I get very large JWT token, that contains lots of information that I don't need.

Is there a way to change te composition of JWT-token? For example, I'd like to only have user id and user role in token.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible via configuration. If you are using some open-source version of OpenAM then of course you can change it to your needs.